# MySQL select doesn't select

Tags: php, mysql

I have been through quite some different codes on this site. To find what wrong with my code. Basically I just want to search in a table and test the result. I wrote something like this:

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','mytable');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$valuetotest = 'something';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE UserName = $valuetotest");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
{ 
    echo "User not found";
}

$password = 'something2';
$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

if($password != $userData['Password']) 
{
echo "Password not found";
}else{ // Redirect to home page after successful login.
            header('Location: welcome.php');
}
?>
```

And I get always **the message :**

```
"User not found." and "password not found."
```

when I know the username and password are in the table...

No I'm quite knew with PHP/MySQL so there might be something quite big right in front of my face and I can't see it!!!!

Can somebody help please. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takes less than a second to spot. (If you had error reporting on it would take even less than that)

1) Your connection is **[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)** but your query call is **[mysql](http://php.net/mysql_query)**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE UserName = $valuetotest");
```

2) Value of `$valuetotest` is a string  value and needs to be within quotes in your query. Should be like

```
SELECT id FROM members WHERE UserName = 'hellohi'
```

And not like

```
SELECT id FROM members WHERE UserName = hellohi
```

And Oh, [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Yes even then you have to use `UserName='$valuetotest'`, but sorry i am not going to suggest something in my answer which can cause harm to your code later. Please move on the prepared statements and see the link i added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT `id`, `Password` FROM `members` WHERE `UserName` = '$valuetotest'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) 
{ 
    echo "User not found";
}

$password = 'something2';
$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

if($password != $userData['Password']) 
{
echo "Password not found";
}else{ // Redirect to home page after successful login.
            header('Location: welcome.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are selecting a text so you should use ' ' Symbols in your Select statement.
Like this:

```
$valuetotest = 'something';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE UserName = '$valuetotest'");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE UserName = '".$valuetotest."'");
```